# Наследование вызванного класса

Tags: php, ооп

Доброго времени суток. У меня вопрос:
Можно ли наследовать вызванный класс, в который уже были переданы данные?
Пример кода:

```
class test1{
public $_test1;

function __construct($send){
    $this->_test1 = $send;
}
}

class test2 extends test1{
function __construct(){
    $this->show();
}

function show(){
    print $this->_test1;
}
}

$obj1 = new test1("TEST");
$obj2 = new test2();
```

Мне нужно свойство _test1 вывести в классе test2 и чтобы в свойстве _test1 было значение "TEST"

Заранее спасибо!

Реальная задача:
Создать класс, который при вызове забирает информацию с БД.
Наследовать этот класс в другие классы, чтобы в последующем вход в БД не осуществлялся, а использовались уже ранее полученные данные.

Comment: @PicanTo, $obj1 и $obj2 - это разные объекты, следовательно, они физически не могут разделить это свойство на двоих. Есть статичные свойства, но это явно не решение проблемы.

> Можно ли наследовать вызванный класс, в который уже были переданы данные?

В класс не передаются данные. Данные передаются в объект при его создании. Объекту нельзя сменить класс, от которого он был произведен.

Лучше опишите реальную задачу вместо абстрактной.

Comment: написал задачу в описании

Comment: продолжаю считать, что ответ такого формата ответом не является и должен лежать в комментариях.

Comment: @PicanTo, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
class obj2{
   private $_test;
   function __constructor($test){
      $this->_test = $test;
   }

$obj1 = new test1($send); // Передаём данные классу для запроса к БД
$test = $obj1->test // Забираем полученные данные

// Далее мы сколько угодно раз можем передавать другим классам в конструктор полученную информацию из БД.

$obj2 = new test2($test);
```

Как-то так.

Comment: Ну это понятно, хотелось в 1 классе обработать полученную таблицу и передавать ее в другие наследованием, без лишней передачи в конструктор. Да и чтобы минимизировать запросы в базу. Без ооп это легко сделать. А вот на ооп решил исхитриться

Comment: При наследовании, как выше прокоментировал Etki, принимается только сам класс без переданных в него объектов.

Comment: подскажите, как тогда мне реализовать мою затею? Или все таки придется при каждом наследовании лезть в базу и создавать нагрузку? Без ООП реализовать легче код, в функциях пишешь $GLOBALS и забираешь нужную переменную.
Верно ли делать так в ООП?

Comment: В Вашем случае при использовании ООП передавать в другие классы объект, взятый ранее, как в моём примере. Получится, вместо $GLOBALS используется конструктор класса.

Comment: спасибо, чет расстроил меня ООП

Answer (score 0):

[@PicanTo](/users/18536/picanto), вы в корне неправильно рассматриваете ООП. Это не серебряная пуля, это иной подход к работе с кодом и вообще систематизации кода. Формально мы могли бы переделать весь ООП в функции типа `имя_класса_имя_метода(хэндл, аргумент1, аргумент2...)`, и ничего бы не поменялось; никто вам и не запрещает (кроме конвенций хорошего кода) использовать $GLOBALS с применением ООП. Вам нужно простое кэширование, которое вообще никак не зависит от парадигмы, оно вообще ни от чего не зависит, просто есть хранилище и его интерфейс, GLOBALS это или еще что - неважно.

> Создать класс, который при вызове забирает информацию с БД.
> Наследовать этот класс в другие классы, чтобы в последующем вход в БД не осуществлялся, а использовались уже ранее полученные данные.

ООП (да хороший код в целом) подразумевает разделение ответственности. Если часть кода получает информацию из БД, то она не должна делать ничего другого, от нее не должны наследоваться непонятные личности, не имеющие отношения к прямому получению данных из БД. Вам нужен объект подключения к БД, который используют все остальные компоненты, и им не надо наследоваться, чтобы использовать функционал другого класса - этот функционал должен быть просто в публичном доступе для остальных компонентов, не более.

Что до не-ООП подхода в PHP: забудьте о нем. Функциональщина осталась как legacy-код, и как только движок более-менее устаканится, команда PHP выпустит последний стабильный релиз, поддерживающий этот legacy и завещает всем использовать его для старых проектов. Остальные подходы приходится реализовывать руками, что, как правило, очень негативно сказывается на производительности и качестве разработки. PHP давно шагнул в парадигму ООП и будет двигаться только в этом направлении.